# How to pass an R variable to a Python variable in Pycharm?

Tags: python, r, pycharm

I am new to Pycharm; however, I want to take advantage of my R and Python knowledge. I am a big fan of both languages, and I am constantly learning more about them.
I am hoping to pass an R variable to a Python variable, similar to Jupyter Notebook.
I could not find any example code anywhere of doing this.

R code

```
x <- 5
```

python code

```
# Some conversion method needs to be added
print(x)
```

Python Console

```
>>>5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible because Jupyter provides its own Kernel that code runs in. This kernel is able to translate variables between languages.

Pycharm does not provide a kernel, and instead executes Python code directly through an interpreter on your system. It's similar to doing `python my_script.py`. AFAIK vanilla Pycharm does not execute R at all.

There are plugins for Pycharm that support R and Jupyter notebooks. You might be able to find one that does what you want.

I usually solve this problem by simply adhering to the Unix philosophy:

```
Rscript foo.R | python bar.py
```

where `foo.R` prints the data to STDOUT and `bar.py` expects to read it from STDIN (you could also read/write from files). This approach of course requires you to define a clear interface of data between the scripts, rather than passing all the variables indiscriminately, which I don't personally mind because I do that anyway as a matter of design best practices.

There are also packages like `reticulate` which will allow you to call one language from the other. This might be more useful if you like to switch languages a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answer! That is great. I did find solution that could help other people that use pycharm.
If you have installed the R plug in option, you can use the following code.

Python code to save to feather file:

````
```
import pyarrow.feather as feather

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/data.csv')
feather.write_feather(data, 'C:/Users/data.feather')
```
````

R code to retrieve feather file

````
```
library(tidyverse)
library(feather)
library(arrow)

data <- arrow::read_arrow('C:/Users/data.feather')
print(data)
```
````

However, this process seems very similar to writing a file to csv in Python, then uploading the csv into R. There could be some type of lightweight storage difference, speed processing, and language variable agnostic/class translation. Below is the official documentation: Git: https://github.com/wesm/feather
Apache Arrow: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html
RStudio: https://www.rstudio.com/blog/feather/